# Need to use powershell to login to multiple IP with the same local user / password no Prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I have a task to check the username and password on multiple servers and report the result.
So basically i have a list of IP's And I want I have the same user and password and need to see which authenticate and which don't.

This is what I found so far but it doesn't seems to work it prompts me for password every-time.

```
$listofServers = Import-Csv '.\Windows Servers.csv'
$username = username
$password = password
foreach($server in $listofServers.ip)
            {

            try{
            $Credentials = Get-Credential $server\$username $password
                }
                Catch
                {
                $errorMsg = $_.Exception.Message
                }
            }
```

Comment: `Get-Credential` does not validate your credentials.  It only acts as an interface to create a `[pscredential]` object.

Comment: Hi Max, what can i use for credentials?

Comment: Never put credentials in plain text in code. It's an unnecessary risk. What you are asking is very basic PowerShell remoting stuff and well documented in the help files, all over the web and via Youtube videos. However, there are only a few commands you can run without being an admin or having PSRemoting enabled,   [Work Remotely with Windows PowerShell without using Remoting or WinRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx)  all else requires you to be admin and PSRemoting must be enabled, or you need to use something like PSExec from MS SysInteranls package.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***
***Removing the previous answer because of our threads below.***

Here's your issue.

You cannot do things the way you are trying because of how Windows security boundaries proper works and you'd also have to set up PowerShell Remoting properly.

You have not said whether you are in a domain or in a Workgroup scenario. Hence the previous statement about setting up PSRemoting properly.

Because you are using a local account, this is like using Workgroup mode in PSRemoting and that requires additional settings to be in place. See the details regarding 'TrustedHosts'.

[about_Remote_Troubleshooting - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7)

Doing a logon to a remote host as you are trying will popup the Logon dialog (Gina) by design.

On your admin machine, try it this way... (tested and validated as working)

```
### PSRemoting - using local machine accounts
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential $env:USERNAME

Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force
Get-Item -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts'
Set-Item -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts' -Value '*' -Force
Get-Item -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts'

$TargetList = 'Lab01','172.0.0.10'

$TargetList | 
ForEach-Object {
    "Validating logon for $($Creds.Username) on target $PSItem"
    Try 
    {
        New-PSSession -ComputerName $PSItem -Credential $Creds
        Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
    }
    Catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}

Set-Item -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts' -Value '' -Force
# Results
<#
Validating logon for postanote on target Lab01

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
 26 WinRM26         Lab01           RemoteMachine   Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available...

Validating logon for postanote on target 172.0.0.10
 27 WinRM27         172.0.0.10      RemoteMachine   Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available...
#>
```

***Update***

Here's a tweak to Doug and my approach and dropping the need to have PSRemoting proper to be involved at all. Again, tested and validated. Except for the one time prompt for the creds, no embedded plain text passwords/files/registry/CredMan storage and retrieval, etc needed.

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential $env:USERNAME
$TargetList | 
ForEach-Object {
    "Processing hostname $PSItem"
    Try 
    {
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$PSItem\$($Creds.UserName)", $Creds.Password)
        (Get-HotFix -ComputerName $PSItem -Credential $cred)[0]
    }
    Catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
Processing hostname Lab01

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn               
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------               
Lab01          Update           KB4576478     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/10/2020 12:00:00 AM     
Processing hostname 172.0.0.10
Lab01          Update           KB4576478     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/10/2020 12:00:00 AM
#>
```

> • Tip: Work Remotely with Windows PowerShell without using Remoting or
> WinRM
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx
>
> ```
> Some cmdlets have a –ComputerName parameter that lets you work with a remote 
> computer without using Windows PowerShell remoting. This means you can use 
> the cmdlet on any computer that is running Windows PowerShell, even if the 
> computer is not configured for Windows PowerShell remoting. These cmdlets 
> include the following:
>
> • Get-WinEvent
> • Get-Counter
> • Get-EventLog
> • Clear-EventLog
> • Write-EventLog
> • Limit-EventLog
> • Show-EventLog
> • New-EventLog
> • Remove-EventLog
> • Get-WmiObject
> • Get-Process
> • Get-Service
> • Set-Service
> • Get-HotFix
> • Restart-Computer
> • Stop-Computer
> • Add-Computer
> • Remove-Computer
> • Rename-Computer
> • Reset-ComputerMachinePassword
> ```

Comment: This code asks for Credentials but I need the code to automatically take the provided credentials like in the example above. $Credentials = Get-Credential $server\$username $password -- Where username  and password are static but the server changes. Also this account is a local account which is why I need to have under user: server\username  password where servername changes for each server.

Comment: It will only ask once. If you are saying you never want it to ask, that means you still have to let it ask once, store that in a file, the registry, or the Windows Credential store and call it from there. There are many articles regarding how to use password securely in Powershell, as well as how to securely store then in a file on disk, registry and credman. There are modules in the MS powershellgallery.com for credman and password managment.

Comment: Ok It asks once example. 10.15.10.1\username  - password= password . Next time it runs I need it to go 10.15.10.2\username -password= password. How is it going to do that? Password can be in clear text that's not a problem.

Comment: You stated that you are using the same creds for every server. So, the username and password will never change. The Invoke-Command is just going to call the next computer with the creds passed on the script block, there is no reason to specific them again per server explicitly. This is a remtoe call so, you'd have to scope the $Creds as a remote variable. See [about_scopes - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Yes but the username is server\username so it's different for each server. When I'm initially asked for credentials which server should i put?

Comment: So, it's not the local use on your admin workstation, but the local user on every target? So, you are not doing a domain logon for each target but a local user login for each server, but it is the same lost username and password., correct?  If so, then that is all you'd use. Each server that invoke calls will use the same creds. If you are saying, you want to use a different username per server, that is a different issue and not what your post is showing. You are passing a single plain text set of creds, which is what I am showing.

Comment: That is correct it's the same local user on different servers. I'm sorry I still don't understand what do I put the first time it prompts for credentials, I need to provide the server\username. But the server is always different.

Comment: just tried to run it for 1 server but it failed. CODE : $Creds = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"
Import-Csv '.\ Windows Servers.csv'| 
ForEach-Object {
    Try {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem -Credential "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$($Using:Creds)"}
    Catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
} - Error: A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only
 if the script block is invoked on a remote computer

Comment: See the changed code. Again, I am not in an environment to test this at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't Understand how to run this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As said more than once, but never too much, you should NOT store a password in plain text. Probably the simplest of the many ways you can store it as a clixml file encrypted by a specific account. You can limit access to the location it's saved to that same account that can decrypt it.

You'll need to use the same username/password in combination with the computer name/IP to build an actual PSCredential object. I assume IP as your code shows `$listofservers.ip` - if the CSV header is not IP, update the code accordingly. I added some feedback to show you which computer and user connected and the fact that it's able to run the command remotely proves the connection was successful.

```
$username = 'localadmin'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PlaintextIsaNoNo' -AsPlainText -Force

Import-Csv '.\Windows Servers.csv' |   ForEach-Object {
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$($_.ip)\$username", $password)
        Try
        {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.ip -ScriptBlock {
                Write-Host Sucessfully connected to $env:computername as $(whoami) -ForegroundColor Green
            } -Credential $cred
        }
        Catch
        {
            $PSItem.Exception.Message
        }
    }
```

The problem with the above code is it will run one PC at a time. `Invoke-Command` runs asynchronously if you just give it a list of computers (up to 32 by default on PS5.1) If you change the structure, this will run much faster. This requires a pretty well known trick which is to provide the username as `.\username` which designates it's a local account. I've tested and it works for me, so please let me know if you see otherwise.

```
$username = 'localadmin'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PlaintextIsaNoNo' -AsPlainText -Force

$serverlist = Import-Csv '.\Windows Servers.csv'

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (".\$username", $password)

Try
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist.ip -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Host Sucessfully connected to $env:computername as $(whoami) -ForegroundColor Green
    } -Credential $cred
}
Catch
{
    $PSItem.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Good additional option Doug, but if the OP is in a Workgroup (which the OP has not clarified domain or workgroup yet), the trusted host this still applies. If not it will error off with... [...Connecting to remote server...failes...].

Comment: Well I can only assume he has set that up and tested interactively. If not he has more problems than trying to authenticate. You still bring up a very valid point. By the way you're one of my powershell heros.

Comment: Yeppers, we all have to assume. ;-}     Thank you for the compliment, it's sincerely appreciated.  ;-}  I do what I can, when I can, if I can, and hope it helps/solves the use case. It's all a learning experience. Seeing things one has seen before and what we have not and taking the challenge to see if we can help.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you both for your help  I haven't tried the other suggestion yet but I tried the first script. And got the following exception even on a machine I know password and username are correct. -ERROR [10.10.10.10] Connecting to remote server 10.10.10.10 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be 
used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit.

Comment: Yes I'm ruining this from a computer that is part of a domain. The rest of the servers could be part of different domains. Mostly they should be in the same domain but I don't know. Also I can't enable PS-remoting anywhere I can't make any changes to those servers. Thanks